# Data Sharing between android and personal computer

Tags: android

I like to make an android app which helps the user to share and send data from application to pc. How i can start doing this. Please help

Regards 
Mohammed Suhail.

Comment: please give us more details. how are these transfers supposed to happen ? via net ? via usb ?

Comment: Via net.I think i can make an web application in php or jsp. and application should contact with that. Is that easy and possible?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible, but wouldn't this be re-inventing the wheel a bit ?

Unless your use-case is really specific to your domain, I would consider something like Astro or Dropbox (that has a very nice Android app) that lets user share whatever data is stored on their phone with their desktop and vice versa.

Doing custom development for this involves proper user authentication & authorization (both on phone and one backend website), user management, sharing capabilities (if required), file syncup, ....

Depending on your needs, a lot of third party apps already offer these kinds of services.

Instead of developing this yourself, I would suggest checking out third party apps that might offer you the ability to integrate with them from your own custom app.